# Add range of occurence of each factor in seperate column (data frame, R)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","DEF","GHI","GHI","JKL"),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
```

I would like to add a column to this data frame that contains the range of the occurence of each factor in column `gene`, resulting in this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","DEF","GHI","GHI","JKL"),
  number = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1),
stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","DEF","GHI","GHI","JKL"),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
df %>% 
  group_by(gene) %>% 
  mutate(numb = row_number())
#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#> # Groups:   gene [4]
#>   gene   numb
#>   <fct> <int>
#> 1 ABC       1
#> 2 ABC       2
#> 3 ABC       3
#> 4 DEF       1
#> 5 DEF       2
#> 6 DEF       3
#> 7 GHI       1
#> 8 GHI       2
#> 9 JKL       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

using `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(
  gene = c("ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","DEF","GHI","GHI","JKL"),
  stringsAsFactors=TRUE
)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, nmb := seq_len(.N), by = list(gene)]
dt
#>    gene nmb
#> 1:  ABC   1
#> 2:  ABC   2
#> 3:  ABC   3
#> 4:  DEF   1
#> 5:  DEF   2
#> 6:  DEF   3
#> 7:  GHI   1
#> 8:  GHI   2
#> 9:  JKL   1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Base R one-liner:

```
transform(df, number = ave(as.character(gene), as.character(gene), FUN = seq.int))
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean the number of occurrences for each value in the column?
this can be  done as

df %>%
add_count(gene)

Comment: No not quite. For example, if  "ABC" in column gene occurs three times, then the the values in column number should be 1, 2 and 3, for each individual occurrence of "ABC", respectively (like in the second data frame I have posted)